# W7, apache, php: 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phptest/phpinfo.php

Tags: php, apache, permissions, http-status-code-403

There are lots of questions on this but I still cannot get it to work.

I am installing Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4.37 on a W7 Pro PC. PHP is running as a load module. If installed respectively in c:\apache24 and c:\php, with the document root as default at c:\apache24\htdocs, it all works fine.

However, I then decided I wanted the document root at f:\webroot (local drive), making necessary changes to document root in httpd.conf. webroot has all the same permissions as c:\apache24\htdocs, but I get the error message in the title.

A normal index.html file in webroot is served OK, it is just any PHP file that isn't.

I noted that the Apache service is started with user LocalSystem. So I tried various others. I even tried running Apache from the command line (instead of as a service) logged in as Administrator, which should have had access to anything, and it made no difference - same message.

Don't understand what is going on. I can go back to the default document root, but at some point will need to access folders elsewhere on the system, so I will be back with the same problem, I guess.

Further info:

Tried various combinations of the commands in <directory "f:/webroot"> to no effect, BUT have found that if in <directory /> I set 'Require all granted' instead of 'Require all denied', it works. However, not sure (a) if that is wise (it probably isn't) and (b) why it is needed anyway. Any suggestions about what I should set it to?

Comment: what about the F:\ drive itself? granting access to a box inside a locked bank vault is useless if you can't get into the vault to begin with.

Comment: Yes it's all the same. If was a simple permissions problem I don't think index.html in f:\webroot would be servable? - but it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this:

Not only do you have to set Document root and the matching <DIRECTORY ...> section entry in httpd.conf, but also DocumentRoot in the <VirtualHost _default_:80> section of the ...\conf\extras\httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Setting 'Require all granted' in <DIRECTORY /> was a mistake.